# How to fix styleq error with React Native and NativeWind in Expo web

Tags: react-native, expo, tailwind-css

I am pretty new in app development and trying to develop a React Native app with NativeWind, Typescript and Expo, but I keep running into errors, when testing out web.

My webpack.config.js:

```
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(
    {
      ...env,
      babel: {
        dangerouslyAddModulePathsToTranspile: ["nativewind"],
      },
    },
    argv
  );

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: ["postcss-loader"],
  });
  
  return config;
};
```

my tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", 
        "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
        "./Screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
        "./src/**/*.{html,js}"
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
}
```

Dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^48.0.6",
    "expo-modules": "^0.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-updates": "^0.16.3",   
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.13",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.2",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.12",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "react-number-format": "^5.1.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.70.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "postcss-loader": "4.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.6",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.2"
  },
```

It works fine on IOS and Android, but when I boot up web, the style is broken, and my console is filled with exceptions similar to this:
`styleq.js:103 styleq: opacity typeof 1 is not "string" or "null".`

**--- UPDATE ---**

I figured it out. It was because I was using `classNames` in `Animatable.Image`. The styles must be added using the style option:

```
<Animatable.Image
            style={{
              width: height * 0.23,
              height: height * 0.23,
              borderRadius: height * 0.5,
              marginLeft: "auto",
              marginRight: "auto"
        }}
        source={require("../assets/image.png")}
        animation="fadeIn"
        iterationCount={1}
        delay={200}
      />
```